# Assigning names to anonymous functions vs. defining them "normally"

Tags: function, racket

Often in the Racket docs/handbook I find something like:

```
(define greet
    (λ (name) (format "Hello, ~a!" name)))
```

I don't see an advantage from this over:

```
(define (greet name)
    (format "Hello, ~a!" name))
```

Assigning a function to a name rather than `(define (ident args...) exprs...)` the normal way seems analogous to the same thing in JS:

```
// "usual" declaration
function greet (name) { return `Hello ${name}!` };     

// assigning
const greet = name => `Hello, ${name}!`;
const greet = function (name) { return `Hello ${name}!` };
```

Or Python (not used because `lambda`s aren't just functions; they're less useful):

```
def greet(name): return f"Hello, {name}!" # full definition

greet = lambda name: f"Hello {name}!"      # not idiomatic
```

- In JS, the scope of `const greet` (local) is different from the scope of `function greet` (global), so prefer `const greet`.
- In Python, `lambda`s can only have one expression which is their return value; you may not declare or assign variables, so prefer proper definitions.

As far as I can tell, there is no difference in Racket to scoping or types of statements allowed between `(define (ident args... ) exprs...)` and `(define ident (λ (args...) exprs...)`.

Why is one used over the other? Is there an advantage? Is it readability, personal preference, or idiomatic-ness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference.

Most people prefer the syntax `(define (greet name) ...)`. If you want to emphasize the functions are values, then it makes sense to write `(define greet (lambda (name) ...))`. At Indiana University the syntax `(define greet (lambda (name) ...))` is used to emphasize that just that (functions being first class values).